# Android - multi-flavor builds in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I couldn't find any solution on SO so I'll just ask it:

For example my project has N customers. Each customer is represented by a flavor and wants to change different type of functionality, each of which is represented by a different class.

In result I have some kind of a matrix:

```
           classA classB classC classD classE
flavorA       x
flavorB              x
flavorC                     x
flavorD                            x
flavorE                                   x

  *x - is a class customer wants to change
```

How can I implement it in gradle with flavors assuming I don't want to use reflections and final code for flavorA should not contain any code from other flavors? Also copying base implementation to all flavors is not a solution either.

Edit:

Maybe I didn't explain it correctly. Each flavor needs to replace only a relevant class with its own implementation and all other classes must remain unchanged.

Comment: Will these classes be used only by classes in the flavor source set?  Or do they need to be referenced from the main source set?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly the way you would do this is to have the different flavors defined in the build.gradle file like:

```
flavorA {
}
flavorB {
}
```

Then if you only have 1 file that should be different it would need to have the same name but in different flavor folders structure like this:

```
src/
|-- flavor1
|   `-- java
|       `-- class.java  // Custom class for customer 1
|-- flavor2
|   `-- java
|       `-- class.java  // Custom class for customer 2
`-- main  // Used for common code
    `-- java
```

The class.java must be named the same and moved from the main folder. But the content will be the different implementation. In that case only flavor1/java/class.java will be used if the flavor1 is build and same for flavor2.

Comment: it's ok when you have one file and two flavors but it's tons of duplicated files if you have 10+ flavors and each modifies different file.

Comment: I thought that the classes in the different flavors was supposed to be different implementations, so that they needed to be different files anyway.